# Is it possible to return mock from mocked method?

Tags: phpunit

I have the Factory

```
class DocumentManagerFactory
{
    ....   
    public function createDocumentManager(): DocumentManager
    {
        return DocumentManager::create($this->client, $this->configuration);
    }
}
```

And I want to mock the `DocumentManager` which returns by `createDocumentManager`

```
    $dmStub = $this->createMock(DocumentManager::class)
        ->method('refresh')
        ->willReturnArgument(1);

    $dmFactoryStub = $this->createMock(DocumentManagerFactory::class)
        ->method('createDocumentManager')
        ->willReturn($dm);
```

I get the following Error:

> Method createDocumentManager may not return value of type PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Builder\InvocationMocker, its return declaration is ": Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager"

Is it possible?

Comment: Which Phpunit version are you using?

Comment: @hakre `phpunit/phpunit                    8.4.3`

Comment: is thee return type type-hinted for the method that should return a mock? IIRC I've seen this "just working" if the type-hints where there. So instead of the standard mock NULL return there was a mock of the return type-hint class/interface. Sorry right now I can't test this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you are chaining your invocations to the mock and then assigning those to the variable. If you split them up it should work without issue.

```
$dmStub = $this->createMock(DocumentManager::class);
$dmStub->method('refresh')
       ->willReturnArgument(1);

$dmFactoryStub = $this->createMock(DocumentManagerFactory::class);
$dmFactoryStub->method('createDocumentManager')
              ->willReturn($dm);
```

In this situation the variable actually holds the object instead of the invocation.